# SQL で特定のカラムを除いて select する方法ってありませんか？

Tags: sql

よく重複除去するのに

```
WITH tmp AS (
 SELECT *, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY uniq_column ORDER BY last_modified desc AS rn
 FROM table
)

SELECT <rn 以外のカラムがずらっと並ぶ> 
FROM tmp
WHERE rn = 1
```

みたいな書き方するのですが
カラム数が多いと記述が長くなってしまうのと
カラムを追加する時に 最後の SELECT 文と２箇所カラム名を追加しなければいけないのでDRYじゃないです
`SELECT * except rn FROM ...`
みたいな書き方ってあったりしませんか？

Comment: そういう使い方をしたい場合は素直にviewを張ったりしませんか？

Comment: FYI: [SQL exclude a column using SELECT * (except columnA) FROM tableA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729197/sql-exclude-a-column-using-select-except-columna-from-tablea)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

残念ながら存在しません
ガッと列名を全部コピペするのがSQL風ですね
SQLはあまりプログラミング的な言語でないので、どうしてもそういう感じになってしまいます

記述があまりに面倒なようなら、SQL では * で取ってしまって、受け側で捨てるのもありだと思います
ただ、列名は明記したほうが振る舞いが明確化されて、不具合などが減ると思います

Answer (score 1):

次を実行するとテーブルtableにおけるカラムrn以外のカラム一覧(,区切り)が取得できますので
これをサブクエリないし動的クエリの一部として使用すれば実現可能と思います。

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(NAME,',') FROM SYS.COLUMNS WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('table') AND NAME!='rn'
```

Answer (score 0):

特定のカラムを除外する方法はありません。

ただ、特定のテーブルのカラムすべてという指定はできます。
少し処理が冗長ですが、このようにしてみるのはどうでしょうか。

```
WITH tmp AS (
  SELECT
   pk, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY uniq_column ORDER BY last_modified desc AS rn
  FROM table
)
SELECT table.*
FROM table INNER JOIN tmp ON table.pk = tmp.pk
WHERE rn = 1
```